# List of user made Object not updating values indivudally

Tags: vb.net, list, object

I'm pretty sure this problem is really obvious, but I can't seem to make due. I have a list of a user defined object (not by me, but I can look into editing if need be). I tried to declare it to have 14 blank objects. That way when I go to listname(5).setvalues(), it only edits that value. Instead it edits all of them (i.e. all 14) in the list or leaves them to be null.

Here's the code:

```
Dim currentProperties As New List(Of ExtendedCamObject)

'create a blank list
For i As Integer = 0 To 13
    '   Dim exp As New ExtendedCamObject
    ' currentProperties.Add(exp)
    currentProperties.Add(New ExtendedCamObject)

Next

propVal = "4012"
currentProperties(8).SetValues(ExtendedCamObject.PropertyTypes.Max_Bitrate, propVal)
```

This leaves them to null. If I do the commented out version instead (removing the other line in the for loop), it sets them all to the same value. Here's the set value's definition in the class definition:

```
 Private m_strValue As String
 Private m_PropertyType As String

  Public Sub SetValues(ByVal ExtendedProperty As PropertyTypes, 
              ByVal strValue As String)
    m_PropertyType = CType(ExtendedProperty, PropertyTypes)
    m_strValue = strValue
  End Sub
```

I didn't write this user object, but I noticed that there aren't any 'get/set' property items from the original coder. Is that why my values are not being set correctly?

Comment: One thing is your `m_PropertyType` is a string and it looks like you trying to set an `Enum` value. Useless need for the CType part as it is not converting or unboxing.

Comment: I can look into changing that, thanks. Do you think it would have caused this effect?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference with the commented out parts and the current one. There are no `Get/Set` because these are fields and not a `Property`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That clears that up then.

Comment: The things in the list ought not be null - in fact unless they are Lazy objects, they cant be Nothing.  That is, `currentProperties(8) Is Nothing` cant be true.  The objects seem largely uninitialized though

Comment: Well, you know what, I asked this question too soon. There's a line of code where I accidentally overwrote all the items before it. It was just an error on my end. Apologies on that one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some code clean up here:

```
Public Class ExtendedCamObject 
  Private _strValue As String
  Private _PropertyType As ExtendedProperty

  Public Sub SetValues(ByVal ExtendedProperty As PropertyTypes, ByVal strValue As String)
   _PropertyType = ExtendedProperty
   _strValue = strValue
  End Sub  
  ...
End Class
```